# I deployed my React App but the API is not working

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, server, web-deployment

I made a really simple app with an API. On LocalHost everything works perfectly fine but when I deploy it the movies do not show up. Could it be that when using npm run build or when deployed the API does not get covered ? The app consists of just a search bar and the container where movies pop up after you search them.

```
import { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import MovieCard from './MovieCard';
import './App.css';
import SearchIcon from './search.svg'

const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com?apikey=********'

const App = () => {

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        searchMovies('batman')
    }, []);

    const searchMovies = async (title) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
        const data = await response.json();

        setMovies(data.Search);
    };

    return (
        <div className='app'>
            <h1>MovieLand</h1>

            <div className='search'>
                <input 
                    placeholder='Search for moves'
                    value={searchTerm}
                    onChange={(e)=> setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                />
                <img 
                    src={SearchIcon}
                    alt='search'
                    onClick={()=> searchMovies(searchTerm)}
                />
            </div>

            {movies?.length > 0
                ? (
                <div className='container'>
                    {movies.map((movie) => (
                        <MovieCard movie={movie}/>
                    ))}
                </div>
                ) : (
                <div className='empty'>
                    <h2>No movies Found</h2>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my `React` App, but the `API` is not working

```js
const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com?apikey=********'
```

> Error is insecure http request make it 'https://www.omdbapi.com?apikey=********'

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34421870)